# Sorting of values based on column name

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I do have the below code to sort the values descending based on three columns and is working fine.

```
hr.sort_values(["SEX","DESIGNATION","SALARY"], ascending = False)
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

As you can see all the values are in descending or in decreasing

So my requirement is i'm looking for a code where the columns **SEX** and **DESIGNATION** has to be in **descending** and only **SALARY** column in **ascending**

Regards

Bharath Vikas

Comment: Could you describe what's the hr object? Because u are using an instance with its method without any details of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass

```
hr = hr.sort_values(["SEX","DESIGNATION","SALARY"], ascending = [False, False, True])
```